# Android Glide - How do I load another image if my original image takes too long to load?

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I'm loading an image from a url like this. If the image is taking a really long time to load, I want to load another image in its place so I used .error() to load an error image if the load fails, but this fail never gets called. Instead, the original image will eventually load after a long time, but I don't want to wait this long for the image to load. I tried using .timeout() but that doesn't do anything.

```
                Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .error(Glide.with(errorUrl).load(imageView))
                .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use placeholder attribute of Glide. Inser your placeholder image inside drawable folder. And use it like this.

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.id.your drawable name)
        .error(errorUrl)
        .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't want a placeholder. I want to completely replace the image.

Comment: It will happen like this. Until you get response from your server you will see placeholder. If the server returns error you will see error image, if it success it will turn into the image you asked. If Glide shows you the image late, check your server response time.

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.id.your drawable name) //this will be shown until actul image load
    .apply(new RequestOptions().override(150, 150)) //for resizing orgininal image 
    .into(imageView);
```

**Note**: Lower resolution in `override(150, 150)` would result in faster loading so choose accordingly.